# How to generate new column with values based on condition in another column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below, I need to generate a new column called "Comment" and for the values specified it should say "Fail"

Input:

```
        Tel    MC             WT

        AAA    Rubber         9999
        BBB    Tree           0
        CCC    Rub            12
        AAA    Other          20
        BBB    Same           999
        DDD    Other-Same     70
```

tried Code:

```
          df.loc[(df[WT] == 0 | df[WT] == 999 | df[WT] == 9999 | df[WT] == 99999),'Comment'] = 'Fail'
```

Error:

```
         AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

Expected Output:

```
       Tel    MC             WT      Comment
       AAA    Rubber         9999    Fail
       BBB    Tree           0       Fail
       CCC    Rub            12
       AAA    Other          20
       BBB    Same           999     Fail
       DDD    Other-Same     70
```

Comment: The error says that `df` is a string and not a dataframe object. Check with `type(df)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for test membership, non matched values are `NaN`s:

```
df.loc[df['WT'].isin([0, 999,9999,99999]),'Comment'] = 'Fail'
print (df)
   Tel          MC    WT Comment
0  AAA      Rubber  9999    Fail
1  BBB        Tree     0    Fail
2  CCC         Rub    12     NaN
3  AAA       Other    20     NaN
4  BBB        Same   999    Fail
5  DDD  Other-Same    70     NaN
```

If need assign `Fail` and empty values use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Comment'] = np.where(df['WT'].isin([0, 999,9999,99999]), 'Fail', '')
print (df)
   Tel          MC    WT Comment
0  AAA      Rubber  9999    Fail
1  BBB        Tree     0    Fail
2  CCC         Rub    12        
3  AAA       Other    20        
4  BBB        Same   999    Fail
5  DDD  Other-Same    70
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of chaining multiple conditions, you have [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) for this:

```
df.loc[df.WT.isin([0,99,999,9999]), 'Comment'] = 'Fail'
df.Comment.fillna(' ', inplace=True)


  Tel          MC    WT Comment
0  AAA      Rubber  9999    Fail
1  BBB        Tree     0    Fail
2  CCC         Rub    12        
3  AAA       Other    20        
4  BBB        Same   999    Fail
5  DDD  Other-Same    70
```

---

Or a `numpy` based one:

```
import numpy as np

df['comment'] = np.where(np.in1d(df.WT.values, [0,99,999,9999]), 'Fail', '')
```

Comment: funny enough, this method is 3x slower than apply and 9x slower than list comprehension. See my timings on 6 million rows.

Comment: I was actually wrong, I forgot to call dfbig. Fastest are now `.loc` with `fillna` and `np.where` on 6M rows

Comment: Nah, I'm testing on 100_000 and its faster than a list-comp @erfan

Comment: Interesting to see that list comprehension is slower than apply though. Did not expect that.

Comment: Yes, from my experience among these two performance differences tend to be quite unpredictable. Added a numpy based one if you want to add it :) @erfan

Comment: Added, roughly the same as `np.where` + `isin`

Comment: I see, nice comparisson there @erfan Looks like the takeaway is, vectorization is the way!

Answer (score 3):

Using `list comprehension`

```
df['Comment'] = ['Fail' if x in [0, 999, 9999, 99999] else '' for x in df['WT']]

   Tel          MC    WT Comment
0  AAA      Rubber  9999    Fail
1  BBB        Tree     0    Fail
2  CCC         Rub    12        
3  AAA       Other    20        
4  BBB        Same   999    Fail
5  DDD  Other-Same    70
```

---

**Timings**

```
dfbig = pd.concat([df]*1000000, ignore_index=True)

print(dfbig.shape)
(6000000, 3)
```

1. `list comprehension`

```
%%timeit 
dfbig['Comment'] = ['Fail' if x in [0, 999, 9999, 99999] else '' for x in dfbig['WT']]

1.15 s ± 18.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

2. `loc` + `isin` + `fillna`

```
%%timeit
dfbig.loc[dfbig['WT'].isin([0, 999,9999,99999]),'Comment'] = 'Fail'
dfbig.Comment.fillna(' ', inplace=True)

431 ms ± 11.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

3. `np.where`

```
%%timeit
dfbig['Comment'] = np.where(dfbig['WT'].isin([0, 999,9999,99999]), 'Fail', '')

531 ms ± 6.98 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

4. `apply`

```
%%timeit
dfbig['Comment'] = dfbig['WT'].apply(lambda x: 'Fail' if x in [0, 999, 9999, 99999] else ' ')

1.03 s ± 45.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

5. `np.where` + `np.in1d`

```
%%timeit
dfbig['comment'] = np.where(np.in1d(dfbig.WT, [0,99,999,9999]), 'Fail', '')

538 ms ± 6.46 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `df.apply` on target column.

```
df['Comment'] = df['WT'].apply(lambda x: 'Fail' if x in [0, 999, 9999, 99999] else ' ')
```

Output:

```
  Tel          MC    WT Comment
0  AAA      Rubber  9999    Fail
1  BBB        Tree     0    Fail
2  CCC         Rub    12        
3  AAA       Other    20        
4  BBB        Same   999    Fail
5  DDD  Other-Same    70
```

Answer (score -1):

the easiest (& comprehensible) way to do it based on your style of coding would be using `numpy.where(df` which is faster than df.apply():

```
df["Comment"] = np.where((df["WT"] == 0) | (df["WT"] == 999) | (df["WT"] == 9999) | (df["WT"] == 99999), "Fail", "")
```

np.where() iterates over the entries/rows of given arrays/dataframe-columns. For more information, see [documentation of nump.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

Hope this helps.